# Why doesn't breaking hydrogen bridges in water increase the temperature?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why, when hydrogen bridges are broken in water as during a phase transition, the input energy does not increase the temperature? Is it because some part of the energy is converted into a rotational and vibrational movement? Or because part of the energy is transferred to the electron cloud and re-emitted? I thought that to break a chemical bonds it's necessary to increase the kinetic energy of molecules in order for them to stretch and not be attracted any more.

Comment: It costs energy to break a hydrogen bond. Melting and boiling are endothermic processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't breaking hydrogen bridges in water increase the temperature?

It does, or can, just not during the phase transitions we are familiar with (melting and boiling, which are [first-order phase transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition)). Such transitions occur at constant temperature until the starting phase has been completely converted into the other, with the two phases coexisting in the interim. Rather than T changing it is the internal energy that changes as exchanged heat is stored (or released). That internal energy is shared among all the possible motional degrees of freedom of the particles in the phase according to the [equipartition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem).

To break bonds in general requires an input of energy (added to the substance in the form of heat if no work is done on the substance). When a phase in which particles locked into a constraining arrangement due to bonds absorbs heat, the additional energy allows the particles to overcome attractive interactions and move more freely relative to each other. Thus for instance ice becomes water as the regular lattice due to strong intermolecular hydrogen bonds breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking a chemical bond requires always some energy (heat or work). ALWAYS.

Making a chemical bond produces some energy (heat or work). ALWAYS.